# How to batch update with google sheets api method "spreadsheets.batchUpdate" by merged row

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets

How to batch update data list then ignore merged row index and  word wrap update data

I need to use the batch update by list = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]], it will become first picture,if list append empty list = [[0], [], [1], [], [2], [], [3], [] , [4], [], [5], [], [6]] will become second picture, If I won't append empty list,how to get the same result with second pic

first pic:

[image]

how to become

second pic:

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: @Tanaike I need to use the batch update by list = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]], it will become first picture,if list append empty list = [[0], [], [1], [], [2], [], [3], [] , [4], [], [5], [], [6]] will become second picture, If I won't append empty list,how to get the same result with second pic

Answer (score 0):

use in A1:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(TEXT(SEQUENCE(7, 1, 0), {"0", "0"})))
```